mySQL set statement converts mixed case characters to upper case
Updating one table from another with this mySQL code:
UPDATE tmp.pictures
    JOIN 
        tmp.fname 
    ON tmp.pictures.fullpath = tmp.fname.fullpath
    
    SET tmp.pictures.filename = tmp.fname.filename;

The filename column from tmp.fname contains values such as NAME.JPG and name.jpg, mixed case and distinct in linux. Resulting values in tmp.pictures are uppercase creating duplicate records.
Is there a way to prevent mySQL from converting these values preserving the original content from tmp.fname?
Full code:
/* create schema using utf-8 encoding */
create schema tmp character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci; 
    
/* create table in schema */
drop table if exists tmp.find_pictures;
    
create table if not exists tmp.find_pictures (
    fullpath varchar(500),
    directory varchar(500),
    filename varchar(500)
    );
    
load data local infile '/home/bcs/find_pictures.csv' ignore
into table tmp.find_pictures
columns terminated by '\t'
optionally enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n'
ignore 0 rows
(fullpath);

/* parse full path into directory and filename */
drop table if exists tmp.fname;
    
create table tmp.fname as
select
    fullpath,
    substr(reverse(substr(reverse(fullpath), position('/' in reverse(fullpath)))), 2) as directory, 
    substring_index(fullpath, '/', -1) as filename
from tmp.find_pictures
where fullpath like '%EMS%';
    
/* update table with directory and filenames */
update tmp.find_pictures
    join 
        tmp.fname 
    on tmp.find_pictures.fullpath = tmp.fname.fullpath
        
    set tmp.find_pictures.filename = tmp.fname.filename;

tmp.fname data
tmp.find_pictures data
EDIT:



fullpath
filename




./ul 4/home/bcs/Pictures/EMS.JPG
EMS.JPG


./u14/home/bcs/Pictures/EMSJKS.JPG
EMSJKS.JPGI


./u 14/home/bcs/Pictures/ems.jpg
ems.jpg




Please add the result of show create table for both tables so we can see the collation and character sets.

Cannot reproduce your issue https://dbfiddle.uk/8xnkjhYC

Mysql does not change values in any assignment operations. My guess is that your join is not correct and pulls in the upper case values from another row. Please provide sample data from both tables and supplu expected results and actual results.

@bcs: Why not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?

@Luuk: Understood, but in this instance an image of the output seemed appropriate.

@bcs: what's wrong with my edit ?

@Luuk: Nothing, was good information in the comment link provided. Thought you were suggesting the images are inappropriate.  Apologies if I misunderstood.
